# How to query date before (month and year) only? (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this filter to let user filter with month and year.
$month = $request['month']; 
$year = $request['year'];

here is what I try to get all the data before the date and year from the table. 
eg: get all data before March 2019. 
 `$result = DB::table('a')->select(*)->whereMonth('date','<=',$month)->whereYear('date','<=',$year)->get();`

but the query above gives me the result of only Jan, Feb for every year before 2019 instead of everymonth before March 2019

Comment: so everything before March **1**st, 2019?

Comment: If you want to filter data by month and a specific year then this can be a solution: 
$result = DB::table('a')->select(*)
            ->whereMonth('date','<',$month)
            ->whereYear('date','=',$year)
            ->get();

Answer (score 1):

Just use a direct comparison against a date literal:

```
$result = DB::table('a')
    ->select(*)
    ->where('date', '<', '2019-03-01')
    ->get();
```

This corresponds to the following raw MySQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE date < '2019-03-01';
```

Note that the above `WHERE` clause is *sargable*, meaning that an index including the column `date` can be used.  The following version you were suggesting is non sargable:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE
    YEAR(date) < 2019 OR (YEAR(date) = 2019 AND MONTH(date) < 3);
```

Here is the Laravel code for that:

```
$result = DB::table('a')
    ->select(*)
    ->whereYear('date', '<', '2019')
    ->orWhere(function($query) {
        $query->whereYear('date', '=', '2019')
               ->whereMonth('date', '<', '3')
    })
    ->get();
```